# Typing out `<kbd>` for every single keystroke is a PITA

Tags: feature-request

Some Stack Exchange sites seem to have custom formatting shortcuts.
For example Code Review has `\$` delimiters for cool MathJax expressions,
which doesn't work on Stack Overflow. Since keystrokes will be very frequently used here, it would be good and important to make this kind of formatting as easy and ergonomic as possible.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem? How is `< any different than \$?

Comment: `<kbd>R</kbd>` is much longer than `\$R\$`. I'm not saying it should be `\$...\$`. But it should be something shorter than `<kbd>...</kbd>`

Comment: It's not clear that we should even be [using `<kbd>` in the first place](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-use-kbd-in-markdown-to-indicate-normal-mode-insert-mode-keystrokes) though.

Comment: I'd propose using square brackets.  Alone, they don't seem to trigger any existing markdown, and `[g][g][=][G]` is pretty easy to type (and even looks like a hardware key)

Comment: @Izkata I'd vote for your comment as an answer.  I'd like to see what other 'extra' markup people will suggest if we start actually taking answers to this question.

Comment: @Byron Hm, I wasn't sure if an answer from a user made sense for a `feature-request`, but since you said that...  Reposted

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Reposting as an answer instead of a comment:</sub>

I'd propose using square brackets:  `[g][g][=][G]`

Alone, they don't seem to trigger any existing markdown (Test: [g][g][=][G]), don't require hitting <kbd>shift</kbd> (at least on a US keyboard), and even look a bit like hardware keys.

<sub>(They're also much easier to type/read/understand when editing than `<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>`, but I think everyone already knew that) (and I didn't even try typing it, I used `:s` in vim ^_~)</sub>

Comment: I like this idea. Personally I use PT keyboard layout which requires me to use AltGr key to type square brackets. But still this is better that using the `kbd` tag. Even if it is only for improved readability.